# How do I drag click consistently on Zebronics Zeb transformer-M

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I bought a Zebronics zeb transformer-M [from here](https://www.amazon.in/Zebronics-Zeb-Transformer-M-Optical-Gaming-Effect/dp/B0819HZPXL/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=zebronics%20zeb%20transformer&qid=1617016236&sr=8-2) (I am still a kid, and so buying a better mouse is not an option). I am able to drag click (right)up to 10 cps, that too not very consistently, and I am unable to keep my mouse at the sane place while doing so. I want to learn how to god-bridge in minecraft. God bridging is a technique where we line up our mouse in the correct angle, and get a high cps rate, and walk backwards while drag clicking so we can bridge fast without shifting.

(drag clicking is a technique where we drag our hands across our mouse to create friction and due to the friction our hand bounces up and down clicking the mouse button rapidly for those who do not know what drag clicking is. Also I am learning it from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfC9iLNVglU&t=342s))

So, is it possible to do this consistently in my mouse, and if so, please give me some advice.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it's a good question, if possibly too focused on mostly irrelevant details (mouse model) and skimping on explanation of the essence - what is godbridging and how drag-clicking is relevant - which makes it confusing for laymen, but they would be unable to answer it anyway - it is an 'expert level' question about a pretty advanced movement technique used in competitive PvP in Minecraft. It IS a vanilla Minecraft technique, so definitely on-topic.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I made changes in my question accordingly

Comment: How many cps are needed for god bridging and are you open to other ways to achieve the needed cps?

Comment: In the video from which I am learning, it says I need 12+ cps, and yes, I am open to other ways of achieving the required cps.

Comment: i can consistently click 20+ cps by spamming, but i can understand this would be a bit hard to do while moving your mouse.

Comment: @Parkerdabiss216 That is very nice. I also tried spamming, but I get around 11 or sometimes 12 cps, and while god bridging, I have to keep my mouse in the same position, but while spamming, I am unable to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find the debounce time listed anywhere on the website, but if you want to try getting higher CPS while dragclicking, try using some regular tape on the mouse buttons or some [Mouse Grip Tape](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08BNB2T2X) by Razer (there's other brands too but this is generally the most popular.) It's for the Viper Mini, but most people use it on other mice just fine. If none of this works, you're better off just trying to butterfly click, it's your next best option. For your whole keeping your mouse in the same place, butterfly clicking is much more controllable, but if you want to keep your mouse in the same place for dragclicking you can try lowering your DPI and/or in-game sensitivity. If you really want to dragclick, I suggest getting another mouse all-together. I find it impressive that you've managed to get 10 CPS on this mouse, as it's only $5 USD. My personal recommendations are the Deathadder Elite for general clicking and butterflying since it has a nice big design, but the Razer Viper and Glorious Model O are great choices for general use and drag clicking. If you want a mouse that specializes in drag clicking, I've heard tons of positive reviews surrounding the Bloody A70 and Bloody A90. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yH5QKJdl2Jo) can help you pick between the two if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks! I will try butterfly clicking. I used a software called xmouse button control to set the debounce time to 1ms. Are there any tips you could give me on butterfly clicking? Thanks anyways.

Comment: @RyugaGod This video (youtube.com/watch?v=UjCXdmczIdI) can help you with the basics, but butterfly clicking is more of a technique you develop yourself because everyone does it differently. Some people like to use different fingers, raise their fingers high, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it helped. :D

Comment: OK, 1 addition, I have been practicing a lot, and now on the same mouse I can drag click 11cps consistently and sometimes I reach 15cps. Turns out you just need to practice a lot, there is no such 'trick' to drag click. I even tried electrical tape but it just made it worse. So I removed it and I am gonna start learning breezily.